# js in angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, angular-cli

I embedded d3 in my angular 2+ application.
I created a barchart component like [this](https://github.com/keathmilligan/angular2-d3-v4/blob/master/src/app/shared/barchart/barchart.component.ts). But I now want to embed [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961) bullet chart. There is a bullet.js file with

```
(function() {
// Chart design based on the recommendations of Stephen Few. Implementation

d3.bullet = function() {
var orient = "left", // TODO top & bottom
    reverse = false,
    duration = 0,
// [...]
```

I now want to import this file so I can make a call from an **angular component**. I want something like `import 'bullet.js'` in the component and then typing something like:

`let chart = d3.bullet()
    .width(width)
    .height(height);`

in my component. Is it possible to import the bullet.js file and use in in my bulletchart.component.ts?

Comment: you can use npm wrapper for bullet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-bullet and then import it as any other module

Comment: @OriPrice Looks good, but there is no doch for the lib.
And in the future I would like also to use other charts in angular component.

Comment: I dont understand the problem. You can use import, just for the embedded module, if you'll want to change the chart in the future import different module. You will want a module that warps the charts in angular 2 (instead of using the lib directly), otherwise you wont be able to benefit from angular 2 library